# Sass – concat to @at-root selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm using @at-root quite a lot (as classes are dynamically being added and removed from the body) and I wondered if something like the below is possible?

```
header.main {
    @at-root body[class*="contact"] #{&}, body.text-single #{&} {
        background-color: white;
        &.header-is--hidden {
            background-color: red; // I know this won't work
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than having to write:

```
header.main {
    @at-root body[class*="contact"] #{&}, body.text-single #{&} {
        background-color: white;
    }
    @at-root body[class*="contact"].header-is--hidden #{&}, body.text-single.header-is--hidden #{&} {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I wondered if something like the below is possible?

**Yes it is**

You can save the header.main selector in a variable
and use interpolation to render it out – like:

```
header.main {
  $sel: &;  //  contains header.main

  @at-root body[class*="contact"], body.text-single {
    #{$sel} {
      background-color: white;
    }
    &.header-is--hidden #{$sel} {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

*CSS output*

```
body[class*="contact"] header.main, 
body.text-single header.main {
  background-color: white;
}
body[class*="contact"].header-is--hidden header.main, 
body.text-single.header-is--hidden header.main {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Well, it works, you're right, but at what price? I'm not sure it's worth making this code more difficult to read than it was already just to not repeat a selector. Readability should be more important than the size of the code.